# Change JFrame multiple times in same event

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am making an updater for my application in Java.However I am facing a problem with frame's glass pane.

Generally my issue is I have a database input panel,which takes inputs from user.
After the user push's next button I want to show an classic progress in order to tell user it is connecting to database.

```
My logic is 
this.glassPane.setVisible(true)
operation
this.glassPane.setVisible(false)
```

But I can't see my glassPane visible,I tried to stop program with threads but that doesn't help.Can you help me?Thanks below you can see pseude-code

```
**public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
if(e.getSource==nextButton)
{
                this.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                glassPane.setProgressText("Connecting to Database");
                this.revalidate();
                this.repaint();
                databaseConnectionPanel.makeConnection();
                //I have thread function in this line.
                this.getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
                this.revalidate();
                this.paint();
}
}**
```

Comment: A long running task in the event dispatch thread blocks it, and prevents drawing from happening during the time. Use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to run the DB operation in the background. (The `progress` bound property is handy for progress bars).

Comment: *"I am making an updater for my application in Java."*  The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Among its many features it includes auto-update.